# PHPUnit - Mockery::mock vs Mockery::namedMocks

Tags: php, oop, phpunit, mockery

I'm writing PHPUnit Test with Mockery, (PHP v5.6.32, PHPUnit 3.7.21, Mockery dev-master) and found something which I can't understand about using `Mockery::mock` and `Mockery::namedMocks`.

My code is below, and the questions are:

1. Am I correct to use in LegendTest.php the `Mockery::namedMock()` instead of `Mockery::mock()` for SignalsCollection object?
2. Regarding to [documentation about namedMock](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/cookbook/class_constants.html#named-mocks), I expect that frist argument is the Class name (`SignalsCollection`) and the second argument should be the extends statement (`\ArrayObject`) - but in my case I'm getting an error: `Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException : Received Charts\SignalsCollection::getIterator(), but no expectations were specified`, so I'm giving only one argument and this works fine. Why? What am I doing wrong? I'm confused.
3. Did I missed something in this test case or should I do something different to make tests better?

Signal.php:

```
class Signal
{
    protected $id = 0;
    protected $colName = '';
    protected $tableName = '';

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setColName($colName)
    {
        $this->colName = $colName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setTableName($tableName)
    {
        $this->tableName = $tableName;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

SignalsCollection.php:

```
class SignalsCollection extends \ArrayObject
{
}
```

Legend.php

```
class Legend
{
    protected $signalsCollection = null;
    protected $graphModel = null;

    public function __construct(SignalsCollection $signalsCollection, GraphModel $graphModel)
    {
        $this->signalsCollection = $signalsCollection;
        $this->graphModel = $graphModel;
    }

    public function getSignalsCollection()
    {
        return $this->signalsCollection;
    }

    public function removeSignal(Signal $signal)
    {
        foreach ($this->signalsCollection as $key => $item) {
            if ($item->getId() === $signal->getId()) {
                $this->signalsCollection->offsetUnset($key);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LegendTest.php:

```
class LegendTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase 
{
    protected function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        Mockery::close();
    }

    public function testRemoveSignal()
    {
        $testSignal = Mockery::mock('\Charts\Signal')
            ->shouldReceive('setColName', 'setTableName')
            ->andReturn(Mockery::self())
            ->mock();
        $testSignal
            ->setColName('testColumnName')
            ->setTableName('testTableName');

        $testSignalSecond = Mockery::mock('\Charts\Signal')
            ->shouldReceive('setId', 'setColName', 'setTableName')
            ->andReturn(Mockery::self())
            ->mock();
        $testSignalSecond
            ->setId(1)
            ->setColName('testColumnName')
            ->setTableName('testTableName');

        $signalsCollection = Mockery::namedMock('\Charts\SignalsCollection')
            ->shouldReceive('append', 'offsetUnset')
            ->andReturn(Mockery::self())
            ->mock();
        $signalsCollection
            ->append($testSignal)
            ->append($testSignalSecond);

        $legend = new Legend($signalsCollection, Mockery::mock('\Charts\GraphModel'));
        $this->assertEquals($signalsCollection, $legend->getSignalsCollection());

        $legend->removeSignal($testSignalSecond);
        $signalsCollection->offsetUnset(1);

        $this->assertEquals( $signalsCollection, $legend->getSignalsCollection() );
    }
}
```